# Problem with this generalised Rice's theorem

Tags: computability, formal-languages, turing-machines

$S$ is a subset of the class of all recursively enumerable languages over some finite symbols then $S$ is recursively enumerable iff

1. If $L$ is in $S$ and $L'$ is a language such that $L ⊆ L'$ and $L'$ is recursively enumerable, then $L'$ is in $S$
2. If $L$ is an infinite language in $S$, then there exists at least one finite subset of $L$ that is in $S$
3. The set of all finite languages in $S$ is enumerable, i.e. a Turing machine can list all the finite languages in $S$

Source of the statement: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2322 and some online notes

Isn't the 3rd one contradictory to the 1st one?

Comment: No. For example, the 'full' class $S$ of all r.e. languages over a given symbol set satisfies the three properties.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump what about the 3rd property? In your eg applying 3rd, we get $RE_{finite}$ a r.e set ($RE_{finite}=\{L|L$ is finite(obviously r.e)$\}$). So $RE_{finite}$ should also satisfy the 1st property, hence it contain an infinite language, which a contradiction.

Comment: No. In this case $RE_{finite}$ should be an element of $S$. This doesn't mean $RE_{finite}$ can take the place of $S$ in condition 1. It $\it could$, however, be used as one of the $L$s.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump NO. $RE_{finite}$ is r.e and its also a subset of class of all recursively enumerable languages, so it should satisfy the three conditions

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. There is some conflict between this new definition of a set $S$ of languages being "r.e.", and the existing definition of a language $L$ being "enumerable" in the sense of 1 and 3, in cases such as $RE_{finite}$, which can be viewed as either type. OK. But they aren't the same, and whoever wrote this tried to emphasize this the way (s)he wrote point 3. (A much better choice would have been to give the new definition a new name.)

Comment: @realdonaldtrump can you explain me what it mean exactly?

Comment: There are two different types of things being called r.e. here. A language $L$ is called r.e. if it can be enumerated by a Turing machine. A class $S$ of languages is called r.e. if it satisfies conditions 1,2,3.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump But I was given another definition for $S$, which says $S$ is r.e if there exist an Turing machine $T$ such that $L(T)=S:=\{<M>|$ where $<M>$ is an encoding of turing machine M such that $L(M)\in S$ $ \}$. And given, this 1,2,3 is equivalent to this definition.

Comment: Again, this new new definition is for a class $S$ of languages, not for a language. (You should delete "$S:=$" from the statement.)

Comment: @realdonaldtrump Where I can find the proof of the statement which is in the question?

Comment: The direction from 1,2,3 to the new definition is trivial. You can prove the other direction as follows. First prove 3 must hold. Now suppose the theorem does not hold, select a counterexample to one of the two remaining properties, and construct an index which defeats a given attempt to enumerate the index set. For example if 1 fails, you take a pair $L_1 \subset L_2$ s.t. $L_1 \in S$ and $L_2 \not \in S$ and proceed as in the proof of the usual Rice's Theorem.

Comment: @realdonaldtrump Okay,  $RE_{finite}$ is r.e and lets take $TM_{finite}$ accepts it. So, then how an $L\in RE_{finite}$ is encoded as input to $TM_{finite}$?